# UAC Patching and Digital Signatures

Tags: windows-installer, uac, digital-signature

We have an application that performs auto-updates. Until recently, we haven't run into any issues.  However, a lot of our customers are finally upgrading to Windows 7 and running into all sorts of issues.

I've been tasked with updating the installer so it works on 7 (and Vista, although it appears none of our customers use Vista).

Based on this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372388(VS.85).aspx), it appears that a standard user can apply a msp patch, provided it's signed with the same signature as the original install.

Does anyone have experience with this?  Does the signature have to be 3rd party verified?  I ask, because I followed this [process](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development) and created my signatures for development, and when I installed on a separate Windows 7 box, it showed an Unknown Publisher and required the Admin to log in.  I assumed it was because it was self-signed.  However, I want to verify before we spend the money to get a 3rd party cert from Thawte or Verisign.

Comment: Side note, you can get *much* cheaper certificates from Comodo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've solved my own problem.

I took the certificates I created on my test box, and manually imported them into my W7 test box.

Once I did this, the patch was able to run without requiring admin password.

Obviously, I can only manually do my importing on test boxes, so I will need to get a 3rd party cert from Thawte or Verisign.

Comment: Or Comodo, which is usually cheaper.